# How to get last month's date from specific date in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza

I have a max date in my query and If the max date  is current month then I want always get previous month’s date. How can I do that?

For example, today is `20160825`. If the max date is `20160801` then I want to get `20160701`. But, if the max date is `20160501` then I just want to get without changes - `20160501`.

```
SELECT
    DEFN_DK,
    MAX(SNAPSHOT_MTH) 
FROM myTable 
WHERE TOT_AMT >0
GROUP BY DEFN_DK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `SNAPSHOT_MTH` column is an `integer` (why?) you can not use any of the otherwise very useful `timestamp` functions. So it's back to integer math, creating a "month" from your snapshot "date" through integer division by 100. This can be compared to `CURRENT_DATE` by converting that to a string and then casting it to an integer. Going back 1 month similarly requires some math. Not entirely efficient, but here goes:

```
SELECT DEFN_DK, 
       CASE max(SNAPSHOT_MTH) / 100
           WHEN tochar(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM')::int THEN 
               ((max(SNAPSHOT_MTH) / 100) - 1) * 100 + 1
               -- or max(SNAPSHOT_MTH) - 100, if you know it always ends in 01
           ELSE max(SNAPSHOT_MTH)
       END AS SNAPSHOT_MTH
FROM myTable 
WHERE TOT_AMT > 0
GROUP BY DEFN_DK;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    defn_dk,
    case max(snapshot_mth)
        when date_trunc('month', current_date) then max(snapshot_mth) - interval '1 month'
        else max(snapshot_mth)
    end        
from mytable 
where tot_amt >0
group by defn_dk
```

Comment: thanks, i am getting this error: Inconsistent datatypes 'INT4' and 'TIMESTAMP' because the snapshot is an integer

Answer (score 0):

show this, two examples:

```
select
case when date_trunc('month',dd) = date_trunc('month',now()) 
then dd - interval'1 month' else date_trunc('day',dd) end
from
(
select '2016-08-04'::date as dd
) d;
```

and

```
select
case when date_trunc('month',dd) = date_trunc('month',now()) 
then dd - interval'1 month' else date_trunc('day',dd) end
from
(
select '2016-05-04'::date as dd
) d;
```